# Auto Compact for delta format not running on Databricks

Tags: databricks, delta-lake

Does `spark.sql("set spark.databricks.delta.autoCompact.enabled = true")`  also work for delta format on, say, HDP, thus not running on the Delta Lake on DataBricks?

Not all features of Delta Lake are available on HDP I know. I ask as I cannot easily find the answer on this one and am indisposed in terms of access to a Cluster. My colleagues are in the dark on this and another unit stated they are developing a compacting script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, auto-compaction (and auto-optimize) is only the future on Databricks. For non-Databricks installations you can consult [documentation on delta.io](https://docs.delta.io/latest/index.html).